# How do I transform a raster image to one with rounded corners (cylindrical to pseudocylindrical)?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I've been working with the altimetry data from topex.ucsd.edu/WWW_html/mar_grav.html

Was having difficulties extracting the data, so I wrote a simple tool to do that. Creates a bitmap form the data source (result [http://imgur.com/MV3ivxl](https://imgur.com/MV3ivxl))

The problem is: I want an image with rounded corners (is there a name for that?) [image: rounded corners]

but when I use gdalwarp, I'm getting a rectangle [image: rectangle].

(actual result from gdalwarp command below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWSeA.jpg so you can see the projection is changing)

Trying to go from Mercator to Robinson:

```
# data readme says source is spherical Mercator, from 0,80.738 to 360,-80.738
$ gdal_translate -a_srs '+proj=merc +datum=WGS84' -a_ullr 0 80.738 360 -80.738 grav.bmp grav.tif
# save http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54030/ogcwkt/ to robinson_ogcwkt.txt
$ gdalwarp --debug on -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=125 -t_srs robinson_ogcwkt.txt grav.tif grav_robinson.tif
```

output from last command

```
GDAL_netCDF: 
=====
Open(), filename=[grav_robinson.tif]
GDAL_netCDF: 
=====
Open(), filename=[grav_robinson.tif]
GDAL: GDALOpen(grav.tif, this=0x1e00740) succeeds as GTiff.
OGRCT: PROJ >= 4.8.0 features enabled
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Target: +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Source: +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Target: +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Source: +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
Creating output file that is 6157P x 3148L.
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(GTiff,grav_robinson.tif,6157,3148,3,Byte,(nil))
Processing input file grav.tif.
WARP: Copying metadata from first source to destination dataset
GDAL: GDALDefaultOverviews::OverviewScan()
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksByte()
Src=0,0,2825x4320 Dst=0,0,3078x3148
0...10...20...30...40...GDAL: Potential thrashing on band 1 of grav.tif.
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksByte()
Src=2574,0,2826x4320 Dst=3078,0,3079x3148
50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
GDAL: Potential thrashing on band 1 of grav_robinson.tif.
GDAL: GDALClose(grav.tif, this=0x1e00740)
GDAL: 8640 block reads on 4320 block band 1 of grav.tif.
GDAL: GDALClose(grav_robinson.tif, this=0x1e05610)
GDAL: 12592 block reads on 3148 block band 1 of grav_robinson.tif.
```

additional info:

```
$ gdalinfo grav.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: grav.tif
Size is 5400, 4320
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (0.000000000000000,80.738000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.066666666666667,-0.037378703703704)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,  80.7380000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 2.63"N)
Lower Left  (   0.0000000, -80.7380000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 2.63"S)
Upper Right (     360.000,      80.738) (  0d 0'11.64"E,  0d 0' 2.63"N)
Lower Right (     360.000,     -80.738) (  0d 0'11.64"E,  0d 0' 2.63"S)
Center      ( 180.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 5.82"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=5400x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=5400x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=5400x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue

$ gdalinfo grav_robinson.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: grav_robinson.tif
Size is 6157, 3148
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["World_Robinson",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Robinson"],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (0.000000000000000,78.093065584271017)
Pixel Size = (0.049619632572081,-0.049619632572081)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,  78.0930656) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 2.63"N)
Lower Left  (   0.0000000, -78.1095378) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 2.63"S)
Upper Right (     305.508,      78.093) (  0d 0'11.64"E,  0d 0' 2.63"N)
Lower Right (     305.508,     -78.110) (  0d 0'11.64"E,  0d 0' 2.63"S)
Center      ( 152.7540389,  -0.0082361) (  0d 0' 5.82"E,  0d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=6157x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6157x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6157x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are doing is that `-a_ullr` is in degrees, and not in the merc projection you are applying in the same step.

This will work:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs merc.txt -a_ullr -20037508 15987768 20037508 -15987768 grav.jpg grav.tif
gdalwarp --debug on -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=125 -t_srs robinson_ogcwkt.txt grav.tif grav_robinson.tif
```

[image]

Another thing you have to care about is that the bitmap ranges from 0° to 360°, while the robinson projection is from -180° to +180°. So the coordinates you get are actually shifted by 180°.

Answer (score 2):

another tool for doing this is this superb freeware: http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/ (for win, mac ana linux): more than 80 projections, just a few simple clicks, do yourself a favour and give it a try

Comment: Sadly that link is down

Comment: @John Barca please try again - its online just now

Comment: Wow, a lot of projections there, and I consider myself a projections geek.